# "evm: execution reverted"

Tags: solidity, web3js

solidity version:0.4.25
web3 version:0.20.1

I write a contract using solidity,and I have finished the test on remix web and it work successfully.When I want to call the contract using web3,the geth console always print info:
 VM returned with error err="evm: execution reverted"
I am very new about solidity,so i can't see what's wrong with my code,please help to finger out my code's fault.Thanks very much!!!

fileEvi.sol:

```
contract fileEvidence{
    struct FileEvi{
        uint caseId;
        bytes fileHash;
        uint upTime;
        address upOperator;
    }
    mapping(bytes => FileEvi) evi;
    constructor () public{
    }
    function saveFileEvi(bytes _hash,uint _upTime ) public{
        evi[_hash].fileHash = _hash;
        evi[_hash].upTime = _upTime;
        evi[_hash].upOperator = msg.sender;
    }
    function getFileEvi(bytes _hash) public view returns(uint _upTime,address _upOperator) {
        _upTime = evi[_hash].upTime;
        _upOperator = evi[_hash].upOperator;
    }
}
```

caseEvi.sol:

```
import "./file_evi.sol";
contract caseEvidence{
    uint CODE_SUCCESS = 0;
    uint FILE_NOT_EXIST = 3002;
    uint FILE_ALREADY_EXIST  = 3003;
    uint USER_NOT_EXIST = 3004;

mapping(uint => address) caseEvidenceMap;
event SaveEvi(address _oper,uint _time,uint _caseId);
event GetEvi(address _oper,uint _time,uint _caseId);

function saveEvidence(uint caseId,bytes fileHash,uint fileUploadTime) public returns(uint code,address addr){
    address fileEviAddr = caseEvidenceMap[caseId];
    if (fileEviAddr == 0) {
      fileEviAddr = new fileEvidence(); 
      caseEvidenceMap[caseId] = fileEviAddr;
    } 
    fileEvidence fileEvi = fileEvidence(fileEviAddr);
    fileEvi.saveFileEvi(fileHash,fileUploadTime);
    emit SaveEvi(fileEviAddr,fileUploadTime,caseId);
    return (0,fileEviAddr);
}

function getEviAddr(uint caseId) public view returns(address addr){
    return caseEvidenceMap[caseId];
}
function getEvidence(uint caseId,bytes fileHash) public view returns(uint _code,bytes memory _hash,uint _upTime,address _upOperator) {
    address fileEviAddr = caseEvidenceMap[caseId];
    fileEvidence fileEvi = fileEvidence(fileEviAddr);
    (_upTime,_upOperator) = fileEvi.getFileEvi(fileHash);

    if(_upTime == 0){
        return (FILE_NOT_EXIST,"",0,msg.sender);
    }
    return (CODE_SUCCESS,fileHash,_upTime,_upOperator);
}

}
```

web3.js:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:50000"));
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
  var eviContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0xe176009923abb13c9215b1a3c10ba3481779a15b");
  eviContract.saveEvidence(9,'0x111111',222222,function(error,result){
     if (error)
         console.log('save evidence error ',error);
     else
         console.log('save evidence successfully',result);
 });
```

Comment: Did you connect remix to the same network that you're using in your web3 script (i.e., the node listening on your local machine port 50000)? How do you make sure that you have an `caseEvidence` instance deployed at `0xe176009923abb13c9215b1a3c10ba3481779a15b`?

Comment: I created a private chain on two local servers and deployed the contract on the geth console as below:> loadScript('../newContract.js')
Contract mined! Address: 0x538b9682d9c415ccb8fb6052ffd6c695b0c32f56

Comment: Well it's not the same address now, is it? Also, did you connect Remix to the exact same network or what?

Comment: yes,it's not the same address.I connect Remix using internet network and test my private chain using the local network.Does the different networks have effect?

Comment: Of course it does!!!

Comment: sorry i can't get it.Can you explain it in detail?I tried delete the line "fileEviAddr = new fileEvidence()" from caseEvi.sol ,it works fine on web3.js.If I run the contract on local network,will "new" another contract  be fail?

Comment: Read the first comment again please. There is no contract deployed at `0xe176009923abb13c9215b1a3c10ba3481779a15b`.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear.I think you may have some misunderstanding."0xe176009923abb13c9215b1a3c10ba3481779a15b" is not got from Remix,it's got from my local network through deploy javascript "newContract.js".So the address is right.I still think the issue is happen in my solidity code.